# Find $\sup \lbrace ab - (\frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^4}{4})\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{A} = \lbrace ab- \left(\frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^4}{4}\right) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \rbrace$. I'm trying to find $\sup \mathbb{A}$. I can suppose that maximal value is for $(a, b) = (1, 1)$, cause $a^2$ grows faster than $a$. However, I'm looking for the method of calculation that supremum and other similar.

I tried to use AM–GM inequality, but without any positive effect. Could you give me some hints or advices?

My try:

$$
ab  + (- \frac{a^2}{2}) + (- \frac{b^4}{4}) =
\frac{4ab  + 2(- a^2) + (- b^4)}{4}
$$
Now:
$$
A = \frac{4ab + 2(-a^2) + (-b^4)}{7}\\
R = \sqrt{\frac{4a^2b^2 + 2 a^4 + b^8}{7}} =
\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{2}a^2 + \sqrt{2}b^2)^2 + b^4(b^4 - 2) }{7}} \\
ab  + (- \frac{a^2}{2}) + (- \frac{b^4}{4}) = 7A \leq 7R 
$$
But we can take any big value for $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use AM-GM, you could try
$$ \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^4}{4} = \frac{a^2+a^2+b^4+1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\ge ab-\frac{1}{4}. $$

Answer (score 2):

We can find the supremum (which in this case is the same as the maximum) without much calculus:
$$ab-\left(\frac{a^{2}}{2}+\frac{b^{2}}{4}\right)=-\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}+\frac{b^{2}}{2}-\frac{b^{4}}{4}\\
=-\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{b^{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\le \frac14.$$
Clearly, we can get to $1/4$ by letting $a=b=\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to maximize a function ($f(a, b)=ab-({a^2\over 2}+{b^4\over 4})$) on an open domain ($\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^+$). Do you know how to find relative maxima of "nice" (polynomials certainly qualify!) multivariable functions?

Comment: Strictly speaking, finding all the relative maxima *won't* immediately tell you the supremum - the supremum might be larger than any maximum, by virtue of not being achieved at any specific point. However, it's not hard to show that, in fact, the supremum in this case *is* achieved.

Comment: No. I didn't have multivariable functions. Therefore it's problematic for me. And therefore I was trying to use AM–GM inequality.

Comment: Have you seen single-variable calculus before? If so, you can find the maximum of $f_a: b\mapsto f(a, b)$ for each $a$, and then again find the maximum of those maxima.

Comment: I did see derivatives and finding maximum of function, but I can't find any help in that. Especially in tasks with supremum of set described by four or six variables. Edit: Ok, I'll think how to use it.

Comment: "Four or six variables" I only see two, $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I have small set of supremum tasks to do. I did more than half of them, but I have problem with few from left part. I suppose, if I make this task, I'll make all other.